# reading an object from a .txt in java

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to write and object to a file then read the object from the file and perform some operation on it. The object gets written to the file fine but when I try to retrieve it from the file I get nothing. The code I used is below:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Date;


public class Driver 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Russian\\Desktop\\file.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        Person person = new Person("B1234","Roshane","Nolan","male","Spanish Town",new Date(),
                "B2134","B3214",150.0,5.11);

        oos.writeObject(person);

        oos.flush();
        oos.close();

        //READING FROM THE FILE

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Russian\\Desktop\\file.txt");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);


        Person object = (Person) ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(object);

        ois.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to Serialize the `Person` object by implementing [java.io.Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)
From the API doc, [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html)

```
  ObjectInputStream is used to recover those objects previously serialized.
```

Code Below(Main function is same as yours:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("src/main/resources/Test.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        Person person = new Person("B1234","Roshane","Nolan","male","Spanish Town",new Date(),
                "B2134","B3214",150.0,5.11);

        oos.writeObject(person);

        oos.flush();
        oos.close();

        //READING FROM THE FILE

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/Test.txt");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);


        Person object = (Person) ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(object.toString());


    }
```

Person Class

```
  import java.util.Date;

  public class Person implements java.io.Serializable{

String arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6,arg7;
Double d1,d2;
Date date1;
public Person(String string, String string2, String string3,
        String string4, String string5, Date date, String string6,
        String string7, double d, double e) {
    this.arg1=string;
    this.arg2=string2;
    this.arg3=string3;
    this.arg4=string4;
    this.arg5=string5;
    this.arg6=string6;
    this.arg7=string7;
    this.d1=d;
    this.d2=e;
    this.date1=date;


    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Person:"+this.arg1+":"+this.arg2+":"+this.arg3+":"+this.arg4+":"+this.arg5+":"+this.arg6+":"+this.arg7+":"+this.d1+":"+this.d2+":"+this.date1;
}


 }
```

Output :

```
Person:B1234:Roshane:Nolan:male:Spanish Town:B2134:B3214:150.0:5.11:Sun Apr 14 23:11:27 CDT 2013
```

Comment: person implements Serializable

Comment: I was able to run your code and it worked for me.. with Person Class being serialized..except that I override a toString() method in Person class. What exact error are you getting?

Comment: I didnt get anything at all

Comment: Hi russian.. I have added the code I used to run, please see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify what you mean by 'nothing'. Are you getting:

- null (that will never happen)
- an exception (e.g. if person class or a field inside of that class is
  not implementing Serializable)
- a string 'somepackage.Person@hashcodenumber' (in which case
  you need to override toString() in the Person class)
- a Person object without any fields set (see the answer below)
- any other string - check your 'toString' method in the Person class

You can add writeObject and readObject to your person class. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) 
{
    // default serialisation 
    oos.defaultWriteObject();

    // write custom fields
    oos.writeUTF(this.name);
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) 
           throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException 
    {
    // default serialisation
    ois.defaultReadObject();

    // read custom fields
    this.name = ois.readUTF();
}
```